# Ethereum client supporting websocket for development

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

Is there any ethereum client for development and testing that supports websocket connection. I want to use the subscribe API in web3.
testrpc does not support socket connection.

Answer (score 1):

Testrpc is deprecated and ethereumjs-testrpc has been renamed to ganache-cli

Please use ganache-cli instead of testrpc for websocket support. Its now stable and can be installed using following command

npm install -g ganache-cli

Or if you a GUI tool to view and manage test blockchain please check following

http://truffleframework.com/ganache/

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger Besu does support websocket. See JSON-RPC API doc : https://besu.hyperledger.org/HowTo/Interact/APIs/RPC-PubSub/